# In python, How do I make a partial function call like this: partial(adder , 2)(4)?

Tags: python, function, nested, decorator, partial

How do you make a partial function that calls like this: function(func , arg1)(arg2). And why/how are you able to do this.

```
f(x)(y).

x  = (func , arg1)
y = (arg2)
```

I thought I tried using decorators to pass a parameter. I can call the wrapper and it works when I call adder(5), for example.

```
def partial(arg):
    def add(func):
        def wrapper(x):
            return arg + func(x)
        return wrapper
    return add


@partial(1)
def adder(z):
    return z

adder(4)
a = adder(4)

partial(a, 4)(5) /////////

###///////////////////////////////another format ///////////

def decorator(func , x):
    def wrapper(y):
        return func(y) + x
    return wrapper


def adder(z):
    return z


adder = decorator(adder , 2)

#########I can call the wrapper, but I get a local error when I call a partial function.
```

Can call the wrapper, but I get a local error when I call a partial function.

I want to be able to get the sum of two or more  numbers using partial functions.

Comment: You're looking for [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use `functools.partial` try e.g a lambda function `adder = lambda x: lambda y: x+y` or

```
def adder(x):
   def g(y):
       return x+y
   return g
```

That should do the job.

You mentioned you want to get the sum of several arguments using partial functions, try:

```
def adder(*summands):
    def h(*more_summands):
        return sum(list(summands)+list(more_summands))
    return h
```

If you want to implement the partial application of arguments to an arbitrary function `f` here is what you can do

```
partial = lambda f, *args1, **kwargs1: lambda *args2, **kwargs2: \
          f(*args1,*args2, **kwargs1, **kwargs2)
```